# is there any way to skip go build if the binary already the latest build

Tags: go, go-build

I wrote a simple bash script to go build then run the binary

```
go build -o my-binary
./my-binary
```

Is there any way to find that my binary already the latest build (no code change)?

Comment: If you use `go install` to build the binary, then you can run `go install -n` to determine if the installed binary is up-to-date.  No output means that binary is up-to-date.  If your goal update the binary before running it, then run `go install`.

Comment: `go build` only does the minimal amount of work necessary, so even a large project will only take a second to run a no-op build.

Comment: Although it doesn't make sense because as the others said go build caches outputs anyway, you can change your scripts to find changed (`git diff-index --quiet HEAD --`) files and if there aren’t any skip the build.

Comment: Maybe a Makefile should be suitable for this task rather than a plain bash script.

Answer (score 0):

script cache go build artifact based on pkg + cmd + go.mod/sum

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# speedup go build/run by reusing local build artifact when nothing has changed
#
# usage: go-fast.sh <regular go run args>
#
# - speed up `go build` by only building when files have changed
# - speed up `go run` by using pre-built binary

# somehow stored and fresh strings can't be compared unless we encode them
bash_encode () {
  esc=${1@Q}
  echo "${esc:2:-1}"
}

cache=/tmp/go-fast$(pwd | tr '/' '-')-build
current=$(find pkg cmd go.mod go.sum -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 md5sum | md5sum)
prev=$(cat $cache)

if [[ $(bash_encode $current) != $(bash_encode $prev) ]]; then
  echo "go build -o main cmd/main.go"
  go build -o main cmd/main.go
  echo $current > $cache
fi

exec ./main "$@"
```

FYI this repo does some general build improvements that might be interesting too https://github.com/kovetskiy/go-fast